# Elements of order $p^8$ in direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I find all elements of order $p^8$ in $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/p^5\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/p^7\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/p^9\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/p^{11}\mathbb{Z}$? I am wondering if I should use the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, or the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Maybe I should use the fact that the order of any element in a direct sum is the least common multiple of the orders of its components? How can I figure out how many elements in $G$ have order = $\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(v),\text{ord}(w),\text{ord}(x),\text{ord}(y),\text{ord}(z))=p^8$?

Comment: Yes, the fundamental theorem and the lcm sounds like a good plan.  Now, do you also know the number of elements of order $p^a$ in a cyclic group?  What are all the orders of all elements of a cyclic group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyclic groups have a unique subgroup of every order dividing the order of the group.

The cyclic groups, $\Bbb Z_{p^9}$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^{11}}$, in this case, each have $\varphi(p^8)=p^8-p^7$ generators for the subgroup of order $p^8$.

We get $p^{15}p^8(p^8-p^7)+p^{15}(p^8-p^7)p^7=p^{15}(p^{16}-p^{14})=p^{29}(p^2-1)$, by taking products.

About the $p^7$ factor that appears, it's because there were still $p^8-\varphi(p^8)=p^7$ elements in the subgroup of order $p^8$ of $\Bbb Z_{p^9}$ that hadn't been used.

---

An easier way is to take the number of elements of order less than or equal to $p^8$ and subtract out those of order less than $p^8$.  Sure enough, you get $p^{31}-p^{29}$.

Comment: How are you getting the $2p^{15}p^8$ part?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I mean, what specifically do you mean by "taking products"? I understand the part about the totient function, but where are you coming up with the expression $p^{15}p^8(p^8-p^7)+p^{15}(p^8-p^7)p^7$? Does this have to do with generators for $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$ etc.?

Comment: Yeah.  I guess you are right, I didn't explain it that lucidly.  I just went for the correct answer.  Let me try to clarify.  I don't need to restrict myself to generators of $\Bbb Z_3,\Bbb Z_5$ and $\Bbb Z_7$, because all of their elements have order dividing $p^8$.  So that explains the factor of $p^3p^5p^7=p^{15}$.  Now I'm thinking in terms of the lcm property that you mentioned.  Do you see where I'm going with this?  To get elements of order $p^8$ I look in the last two factors: $\Bbb Z_{p^9}$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^{11}}$.  The other factors aren't big enough to have elements of order $p^8$.

Comment: Sorry.  There were some typos above.  I left some $p$'s out.  Anyway,  both $\Bbb Z_{p^9}$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^{11}}$ have $\varphi(p^8)$ elements of order $p^8$.  Are you with me?

Comment: Okay, I see the factor of $p^{15}$ now, so where do we get the sum from? Is it because we can pick a generator from $\mathbb{Z}_9$ *or* $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107248/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-sunyata).

Comment: @ChrisCuster Why wouldn't the $p^8$ in the first term of your sum be $p^7$? The subgroup of order $p^8$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{11}\mathbb{Z}$ has $\phi(p^8)$ generators, which leaves $p^7$ other elements in the subgroup of order dividing $p^8$, just like in your second term. I also read you discussion in chat and don't believe my question was addressed.

Comment: I believe it should actually be $p^{15}p^8p^7(p^8 - p^7)$, because you have $p^{15}$ elements in the first 3 factors dividing $p^8$, then you have $p^8$ elements in the factor $\mathbb{Z}/p^9\mathbb{Z}$ of order dividing $p^8$, and then you have $p^7(p^8-p^7)$ elements in the factor $\mathbb{Z}/p^{11}\mathbb{Z}$ of order dividing $p^8$. What do you think?

Comment: You can't choose both a generator and a non-generator from the subgroup of order $p^8$ in $\Bbb Z_{p^{11}}$ at the same time. Btw, I read something recently that suggests an easier way to do this. I want to try it and see if I get the same answer. The method is to count elements of order less than or equal to $p^8$ and subtract the number of elements of order less than or equal to $p^7$. @Travis62

Comment: @Travis62 yep.  It agrees.

Comment: Isn't that what you did in the second term of the sum though? With the $p^{15}p^7(p^8 -p^7)$? That's what I gathered from your explanation in chat. And actually I've heard of the method you just suggested, but forgot about it. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Travis62 it appears both solutions were correct.  It's been awhile, but the first method appears to be a slightly more laborious way of breaking it down.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, much simpler that way. Took all of 5 seconds, lol. Good deal.

Comment: Nice catch.  @Travis62

Comment: And your explanation on the first way finally makes sense to me.  All is good. Anybody reading this ignore my comments above.